# KNN multiple max occuring class

Tags: machine-learning, classification, knn

If in KNN classifier with K=7, suppose i have classified image pixels based on euclidean distance and got an array of size 7 with 3 belonging to class 11, 3 to class 12 and 1 to class 2, to which class should i classify that object to?(I just simply excluded those classes) Or what other case should i include to handle it. Please suggest using scikit-learn or any other python library.This is the code for that array:

```
# storing class numbers
new_dist=mat_dist[np.argsort(mat_dist[:,0])]                         # to sort by distances                                     
counter= np.zeros((17,))
for x in range(k):
    counter[int(new_dist[x][1])]+=1

if np.count_nonzero(counter == max(counter))>1:
    class_index=-1
    exclusion+=1                                    # cases of more than one class with max occurence is excluded
else:
    class_index = np.argmax(counter)
```